# Cannot import excel file into SAS using proc import

Tags: sas

I am getting the error :

```
ERROR: Connect: Class not registered
```

when I try to import an xls file into SAS 9.4 using:

```
proc import out=test datafile="C:\Users\test_201801.xls"
  DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE;
GETNAMES=YES;
run;
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try DBMS=XLS instead.

Answer (score 0):

`CLASS NOT REGISTERED` typically comes when you are importing using a wrong-bitness version of Excel (typically, you have 64 bit SAS and 32 bit Excel).

You can work around that a number of ways.  As Reeza alluded to, you can use the old `DBMS=XLS`, though I think that's close to being deprecated and I'm not sure it works in every combination of OS/bitness/SAS version anymore.  You can fix your bitness (get 32 bit SAS or 64 bit Excel).  You can use a PC Files Server (including hosting one on your own machine).  If you're using Enterprise Guide, you can use the built in Import File tool which is totally different from PROC IMPORT.

There are some other causes for this error, but this is the most common.  To see SAS's official explanation for this plus some other potential causes, see the [KB article 43933](http://support.sas.com/kb/43/933.html).

Comment: Thank you. When i use dbms=xls, I get:

Comment: The Microsoft Access Engine is probably not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, Excel import depends on the Microsoft Access Engine redistributable being installed.  Sas installs it automatically, but it may have been uninstalled somehow.  This must be a common problem.  Example download link for the redistributable (2016):  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Silent install guide:

https://silentinstallhq.com/microsoft-access-database-engine-2016-redistributable-silent-install-how-to-guide/